# I do not work the history.pushState

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, pushstate

See if you can lend me a hand, I tried to apply the history.pushState jquery code does not work, I know very little about how to implement the history.pushState and beg a little help in this regard. Then I hit my code...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/></script>

  <script>



function cargar(div, desde)

{
     $(div).load(desde, function() {

}); 
 init();

  $(document).on("click", "a, area", function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    history.pushState({}, '', href);
    $main.load(href + " main>*", ajaxLoad);
    return false;
  });
  history.pushState(pageData, pageData.title, pageURL);

}




</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="botones">
<ul class="menu-galeria">
 <li><a href="#1" onClick="cargar('#cambia','1.php')">CAMBIO 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#2" onClick="cargar('#cambia','2.php')">CAMBIO 2</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>


<div id="cambia">
Hola cambio
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

1.php and 2.php is simple text

Comment: If you're new to browser-scripting I wouldn't try using `history.pushState()` for a while. If you must then I would suggest you make it someone else's problem by using [jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in this way, for if it helps someone help.

```
   <!doctype html> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
        <title></title> 
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script> 
            $( document ).ready(function() { 
                $( ".loadContent a" ).click(function() { 
                    var file = $(this).data("file"); 
                    $('#content').load(file, function(){ 
                        window.history.pushState({id: file}, file, file); 
                        return false; 
                    }) 
                }); 
            }); 
        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <ul class="loadContent"> 
        <li><a href="#" data-file="file1.php">bot1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#" data-file="file2.php">bot2</a></li> 
    </ul> 

    <div id="content"> 
      I'm going to change
    </div> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```